# Error when trying to populate JTable from mysql using arraylist

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I have tried to populate data from mysql to `JTable`

Although i got the size of rows printed. i couldnt figure out what's wrong  on the for loop

used the following code and now i got error as mentioned in the end. however, the query works on DBMS.

One to select data from database

```
public class Search{
 public ArrayList<String []> select_by_book(){
        ArrayList<String []> data = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        String query="select * "
                + "from detail d "
                + "join user_editor_author uea on d.detail_id = uea.detail_id "
                + "join author a on a.author_id = uea.author_id "
                + "join editor e on e.editor_id = uea.editor_id "
                + "join user u on u.user_id = uea.user_id"
                + "where d.reference_type = 'book'"
                + "and u.user_id="+LogInAndRegister.id;

        ResultSet rs = connect.get(query);
        while(rs.next()){
            String tmp[] ={rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4),rs.getString(5)
                    ,rs.getString(6),rs.getString(7),rs.getString(8),rs.getString(9),rs.getString(9),
                    rs.getString(10),rs.getString(18),rs.getString(20)};

            data.add(tmp);
        }
        rs.close();
        return data;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Search.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }
}    
 }
```

Populate table method on the class with table:

```
 public class SearchGui{

DefaultTableModel dtm ;
ArrayList<String[]> database;
Search thisSearch=new Search();

 private void populateTable(){ 
        dtm=(DefaultTableModel)jTable.getModel();
        database = thisSearch.select_by_book();
       // System.out.println(thisSearch.all_reference().size());

        for(Object data[]:database){
            dtm.addRow(data);

        }
    }}
```

The error that i got:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'd.reference_type = 'book'and u.user_id=1' at line 1

mysql query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `author` (
  `author_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`author_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `detail` (
  `detail_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `issn` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volume` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `issue` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_page` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_page` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `publisher` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `reference_type` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`detail_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `editor` (
  `editor_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `editor_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`editor_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson i am a  beginner and i have only few ideas about how i should ask question. Would u recommend me to add my db table snapshot too

Comment: I'd recommend you read that link again, carefully, since there is no MCVE appearing above.

Answer (score 1):

> the first row of the table has checkbox but not others. So, i havent populated the first column.

What do you mean you haven't populated the first column? You are using the addRow(...) method to add data to the TableModel, so the first column will always have data from the first entry in the array.

> i couldnt figure out what's wrong on the for loop

```
dtm.addRow(new Object[]{i+1,data[1]});
```

The first Object in your Array is an Integer, NOT a Boolean.

> i have tried to populate data from mysql to jtable. the first row of the table has checkbox but not others.

That is not the way tables work. Data needs to be consistent in the columns, otherwise you need to customize the JTable behaviour.

Unless you post demo code (with hard coded data because we don't have access to your database) that attempts to show what you are doing we can't provide any real suggestions.

Edit:

Here is an example of a `SSCCE` that works:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public SSCCE()
    {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 3);
        model.addRow( new Object[] { "1", "2", "3" } );
        model.addRow( new Object[] { "one", "two", "three" } );

        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        add( new JScrollPane(table) );
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new SSCCE());
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Post your SSCCE that doesn't work so we can see what the data is that you are trying to load into the TableModel. This is how you simplify the problem so we can understand what you are doing. Again your database is irrelevant.

Comment: how do i make the first column boolean. and  how do i customize the JTable behaviour. i was told it would but i didnt know how to.

Comment: `how do i make the first column boolean` - you add a Boolean.TRUE value to the column. Post a runnable example if you want more help showing what you are doing. Again we don't have access to your database so the data you add to the table model will need to be hard coded.

Comment: would u help me? i think i i have provided the table query. i can provide the inserted values too. also i have changed the code on populateTable().

Comment: Twice I told you the database is irrelevant. You have been asked by me and Andrew to post a runnable example and you haven't yet. You can't find a solution to your problem because you don't even know what problem you are trying to solve. Create a JTable. Add one row of data to it that contains a Boolean value. Then add a second row that doesn't contain a Boolean value. That is your problem. That is forget about the database and hardcode the addRow(...) statement for two row of data. So the data replicates the problem without the use of a database. Until this is done I can't help.

Comment: @SaugatThapa, see my edit or an example of a `SSCCE`. Your `SSCCE` should generate the `ClassCastException`. Andrew gave you a link to define what a SSCCE is. So click on the link if you need more explanations.